# Is there a other way to use Maybe on my path search function through the BTree? (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I want to be able to specify an element and the tree and the function should give me a list of directions and if the element is not contained it should not return an error but rather a "Nothing" made by Maybe.

```
data BTree a = Nil | Node a ( BTree a) ( BTree a) deriving Show

data Direction = L | R deriving (Show , Eq)

 getPath :: (Ord a) => a -> BTree a -> Maybe [Direction]
   getPath y (Node x lt rt)
    | (Node x lt rt) == Nil = Nothing
    | y == x = Just []
    | y < x = Just (L:(getPath y lt))
    | otherwise = Just (R:(getPath y rt))
```

But with this code i am getting an error:

```
    * Couldn't match expected type: [Direction]
                  with actual type: Maybe [Direction]
    * In the second argument of `(:)', namely `(getPath y lt)'
      In the first argument of `Just', namely `(L : (getPath y lt))'
      In the expression: Just (L : (getPath y lt))
   |
57 |   | y < x = Just (L:(getPath y lt))

    * Couldn't match expected type: [Direction]
                  with actual type: Maybe [Direction]
    * In the second argument of `(:)', namely `(getPath y rt)'
      In the first argument of `Just', namely `(R : (getPath y rt))'
      In the expression: Just (R : (getPath y rt))
   |
58 |   | otherwise = Just (R:(getPath y rt))
```

It would be great if someone could help me.

Comment: Recursing as in `Just (L:(getPath y lt))` would lead to things like `Just (L: (Just (L: (Just (L: ...` which are ill-typed. We don't want those extra `Just`s. Using `fmap` as pointed out in the answer below is the way to go.

Comment: `Node x lt rt` cannot equal `Nil` (at least, not without a broken `Eq` instance).

Comment: Be aware that there is a data structure named [B-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), so it can be confusing to use that name for binary trees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason `Just (L : getPath y lt)` does not work is because `getPath y lt` is a `Maybe [Direction]`, not a `[Direction]`, hence it is not a list, and you thus can not prepend this with `L` or `R`.

You can make use of [**`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) to perform a mapping on the item wrapped in the `Just` data constructor, and `fmap f Nothing` will return `Nothing`.

You thus can implement this as:

```
getPath :: Ord a => a -> BTree a -> Maybe [Direction]
getPath Nil = Nothing
getPath y (Node x lt rt)
    | y == x = Just []
    | y < x = fmap (L:) (getPath y lt)
    | otherwise = fmap (R:) (getPath y rt)
```

The condition `(Node x lt rt) == Nil` can never be `True`: you should pattern match on `Nil`, and in that case return `Nothing`.